# Rails + Searchkick - Random search with conditions not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I need to get a random amount of results based on certain conditions. This is my query:

```
query = Company.search('*', limit:10, where: {location: {near: [long,lat], within: distance}, confirmed: true }, execute: false)

query.body[:query] = {function_score:{ random_score: { seed: seed } } }

company_results = query.execute.results
```

Problem is that it's returning the returning the search with the randomness but not applying the where parameters. It's just giving me 10 random companies from the database each time. Have searched for hours on how to fix this but no luck. Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in case anyone runs into the same issue. Turns out the entire query needs to be written in the body hash

```
query = Company.search '*', body: { size: 10, query: { function_score: { query: { filtered: { query: { term: { confirmed: true } }, filter: { geo_distance: { distance: "150km", location: "#{lat}, #{long}" } } } }, random_score: { seed: DateTime.now.to_i } } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into similar requirement; I used the following to get pretty good result:

```
order_params = {
      "_script" => { 
        "script" => "(doc['created_at'].value + doc['user_id'].value + _score).hashCode()",
        "type" => "string",
        "order" => "desc"
       }
    }
Model.search "*", {order: order_params}
```